# Прикрепление файлов в WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть сайт мобильной версии, там в форме есть input для файла. Туда надо прикрепить файл.
Никак не могу разобраться в прикрепление файла в input.

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package ru.test.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://test.test/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
        {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }
    });

            setContentView(mWebView);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.econordit.inhouse">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Что в логе? что в консоли браузера (открываете Chrome на машине разработчика и присоеденяетесь к веб вью)? Как обрабатывается загрузка файла? Вообще по умолчанию вебвью при наличии permission нормально присоеденяет файлы.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь переопределить `openFileChooser` - недокументированный метод в `WebChromClient`, но не в `WebViewClient`, к тому же на актуальных API у него другая сигнатура: `public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFile, String acceptType, String capture)`. Ну и, собственно, разве без извращений не работает, разрешения на чтение файлов объявлены, а получены?

Comment: @woesss права все были поставлены, чтение файлов никак не заработал

Comment: Перенесите Ваш метод в `WebChromeClient` и добавьте параметры, что бы метод соответствовал сигнатуре. А для API21 и выше есть уже легальный метод [`onShowFileChooser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams))